# How to declare a module with simple one-file project

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, declaration-files

I am trying to import my library like so:

```
import jsonStdio = require('json-stdio');
```

I am getting this error: **TS7016** -
[image]

The library in question is here:
https://github.com/ORESoftware/json-stdio/blob/master/index.ts

does anyone know how I can properly create a module so that it can imported using `import x = require('x')` syntax with TS?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, all I had to do was add the `package.json` file for the `json-stdio` project:

```
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
```

if there is a better/different way to do it, someone please let me know, but because I missing one of those lines (I always add both, just because), then it didn't recognized my `.d.ts / declaration` file in my `json-stdio` project.